# joining 2 elements at once

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

What is the most elegant way to join 2 by 2 elements from array in Ruby?

For instance:
I want to join array:

```
ar = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
```

and get

```
ar = [ '12', '34', '5' ]
```

Thanks for help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As usual, [Enumerable](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice) is your good friend and wants to make your life easier:

```
ar.each_slice(2).map(&:join)
```

The only trick is using the blockless form of `each_slice` to get an enumerator that you can `map` to join the slices.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about *elegant*, but this is something I just whipped up:

```
ar.each_slice(2).map { |x, y| "#{x}#{y}" }
```

You don't necessarily have to give a block to [`each_slice`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice), it just returns an enumerator. So one can call `map` on it, pass it the two pieces of each slice, and return a nice new array.